# Get user profile information via ASP.NET Membership.OpenAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Using Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth I've very quickly been able to get an app logging people in via various external provider (facebook, twitter, google, microsoft).  That's great.

My question is, can I use this framework to get the users profile information easily?  I'd like to get their profile picture, email address, DOB etc if the service has them.

I know there is some extra information in AuthenticationResult.ExtraData however it isn't standard and doesn't contain what I need.

Is there something I can do from here to get the information using Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth (or another .net lib) or will I need to use the access token in ExtraData to access the different services manually via the separate service APIs?

Thanks

Comment: +1 Good question but I have the hunch that this depends mostly on how the application is set up on each of those providers. For instance, if you tell Facebook that your application should request access to contacts, picture, email, and so on, then when the user is redirected to facebook's login page he should specifically grant you access to all of that. Once your site is called back, it's very likely that all of that information is accessible to you... that's just my guess, I am interested in seeing some answers to this.

Comment: I think you need to Register your website with certain external Providers, like Facebook as an example before you can gain access to the users Facebook Profile data.

Comment: You need to register with most (if not all) the providers to even log people in using the OpenAuth lib.

Comment: On facebook you need to ask for email address specifically in the permissions for the app (on developer.facebook.com).

Going have a further look this morning and see where I get to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues to overcome with the authentication workflow stuff. One, as the OP rightly pointed out concerns the contents of `ExtraData` and the other concerns the permissions that you need to ask Facebook for. In the end I went with the `DotNetOpenAuth` library rather than the Microsoft one but extended it in certain places by rolling my own classes and borrowing parts of the framework where necessary.

The first thing I did was create a `FacebookClient` that extended the `OAuth2Client` from `DotNetOpenAuth` and allowed me to pass in a value for `scope`, which got past the limitation on which data you could request from Facebook. The permission I ask for are `publish_stream, manage_pages, email, user_interests`. They simply get appended to the service login URL and passed across to Facebook. The useful method within my implementation of `OAuth2Client` is `GetUserData`:

```
    protected override IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessToken)
    {
        var token = accessToken.EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986();
        FacebookGraphData graphData;
        var request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0}", token));
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                graphData = JsonHelper.Deserialize<FacebookGraphData>(responseStream);
            }
        }

        var userData = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"accessToken", accessToken}};
        userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("id", graphData.Id);
        userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("name", graphData.Name);
        userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("email", graphData.Email);
        userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("firstName", graphData.FirstName);
        userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("lastName", graphData.LastName);
        userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("link", graphData.Link == null ? null : graphData.Link.AbsoluteUri);
        userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("username", graphData.Username);
        userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("gender", graphData.Gender);
        userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("locale", graphData.Locale);

        FacebookFriendData friendData;
        request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token={0}", token));
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                friendData = JsonHelper.Deserialize<FacebookFriendData>(responseStream);
            }
        }

        if (friendData.Friends != null)
        {
            userData.Add("connections", friendData.Friends.Count().ToString());
        }

        return userData;
    }
```

I've basically created a few data classes that are deserialized when the response comes back from Facebook. I can also make any other Graph API calls from here that I need. Serialization classes look like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class FacebookFriendData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public IEnumerable<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Friend
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class FacebookGraphData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "link")]
    public Uri Link { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "locale")]
    public string Locale { get; set; }
}
```

As per @radm4 I still check the provider string to decide which methods to call in certain places - still working on a more elegant solution to that one...

Comment: Thanks levelnis,

That is basically the conclusion I came to, your solution is nice in that it extends what is already there, I think I'll try and adopt this way of doing it too.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around I can't see a way to do this only with the Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth stuff.

My solution has been to skip the .NET oauth stuff if the user wants to use facebook.  In this case I use the facebook C# SDK to authenticate and then I can access email, birthday, photo etc.

```
if(provider != "facebook")
{
    //do normal oauth
}
else
{
                 FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient();

                var loginUrl = client.GetLoginUrl(new
                {
                    client_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookId"],
                    client_secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookClientSecret"],
                    redirect_uri = redirectUrl,
                    response_type = "code",
                    scope = "email,user_birthday"
                });

                Response.Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

When the user returns you can then use the SDK to access this extra information.

I'm going to add this type of thing for Google too.  If users want to use other services to log in they can but I'll just use asp.net oauth and they won't get as customised an experience as facebook or google until I have more time to spend on each provider.

So basically the answer is ASP.net oauth is fine for logging in and very basic information but if you need more you'll need to extend or by pass it for each provider.

Comment: Also for anyone wondering as far as I have gathered the best google API for this same function is http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2 and the other APIs that work with it such as google+ etc